# removing special characters natively in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, glob

I am looking to create a string natively in sqlite3 that will gather all non-numeric values, however the column format has all data in TEXT format and wrapped with [""] such as:

["1234567"]
or
["word"]

there is no mix of numbers and letters, but I am unable to build a string that parses just the non-numeric values within sqlite itself.  Closest I have requires sed and grep after (novice at best with any language and am learning daily) which would result in 'word', with the above examples as values:

sqlite3 data.db "select DISTINCT column from table ORDER BY column" |sed 's/[][]//g'|sed 's/"//g' | grep -v '[0-9]'

word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *there is no mix of numbers and letters* you can get all the rows with non-numeric chars with the operator [`GLOB`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_and_match_operators):

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE col NOT GLOB '*[0-9]*';
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=842e7cb9c192297be1b811b6f075634f).

Comment: Perfect.  I had tried the % wildcard, completely missed or neglected the *.  That worked like a charm thank you!